# Scoping email to subdomain in devise rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise for authentication in rails app, and my app can have many subdomains.
Currently it is using email as authentication, and email should be unique for the whole app.

Now is there any way I can scope uniqueness of email address to subdomain, not the whole app?
I tried:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :email, :scope => :account_id
```

But didn't work. It still seeks uniqueness of email to whole app, not the specific subdomain when registering a new user.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the subdomain name stored in the User table?

Comment: I have Account model which stores subdomain name. And the Account has has_many relation with User model. And I tried above mentioned validates_uniqueness_of in my User model but in vain.. :(

Comment: Could you please add a basic gist of the models (Account, User) with the relations (has_many, belongs_to) between them and the relevant attributes they store?

Comment: Here it is: https://gist.github.com/1022286

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok I did this way. 
 
Edited config.authentication_keys in devise.rb as

```
config.authentication_keys = [ :login, :account_id ]
```

Also I created hidden field to include account_id in login form

```
<%= f.hidden_field :account_id, :value => @account.id %>
```

Here @account hold the account related to current subdomain.

And added the following protected method in user.rb to override find_for_database_authentication class method

```
protected
def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
conditions = warden_conditions.dup
login = conditions.delete(:login)
account_id = conditions.delete(:account_id)
where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).where("account_id = ?", account_id).first
end
```

If there is better solution then feel free to comment guys.. 
Cheers!

Comment: is there a way to, instead of having account_id be on the form, to find it from the subdomain? For larger applications, it's not comfortable to expose account ids. :-\

Comment: How to make confirmation work with user email scoped by account_id?

Answer (score 0):

How are you saving your users, are you setting the account on the user model before trying to save it? If not then you will be scoping to an account_id of nil - hence it will look like there is no scope.